# Shopify order confirmation email does not shows if condition statement for out of stock product,

Tags: shopify, liquid, newsletter

My task is fairly straightforward but seems it doesn't. I am attempting to send the order confirmation email for out of stock product i.e whose inventory is zero or less. I am allowing to place out of stock order and wants to send order confirmation email as `An order will be dispatched by June 17` in email body else for in-stock product just normal email as `An order takes about 4-6 business days to be delivered.` 
I have used the combination of a variable to set conditional statement in order Confirmation newsletter edit box as below:

```
{% capture email_title %}<h2 style ="color:#F15A25">Thank you for your purchase!</h2> {% endcapture %}
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2202/5979/files/OrderSuccessEmail_jpg.png?1379574749859827384" style="display: block;    margin-left: auto;    margin-right: auto;" width="570" height"150"/>
{% capture email_body %}
  {% if requires_shipping %}
    Hi {{ customer.first_name }}, we're getting your order ready to be shipped. Please look out for an email with tracking information.

 {% if variant.inventory_quantity < 0 %} Will be dispatched by June 7

  {% else %} An order takes about 4-6 business days to be delivered. {% endif %} But there's more good news, read below!<br><br>



<span style ="color:#F15A25">Get Rs. 250 cash back</span>- if you love our product, leave us a review on our website at the https://winknod.com/pages/reviews and we will refund you Rs. 250! No questions asked. <br> <br>

<span style ="color:#F15A25">100 Nights Trial</span> - Your 100 nights trial will start on the day your mattress is delivered. Please make sure to save the originally signed invoice otherwise we will not be able to entertain returns. Also, ensure that mattress is not damaged and there are no stains on a cover for returns to be approved. Please read the return Terms & Conditions here:
<br>
https://winknod.com/apps/help-center/#!tell-me-more-about-the-100-nights-trial
  {% endif %}
{% endcapture %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>{{ email_title }}</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/notifications/styles.css">
  <style>
    .button__cell { background: {{ shop.email_accent_color }}; }
    a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited { color: {{ shop.email_accent_color }}; }
  </style>
</head>

  <body>
    <table class="body">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table class="header row">
  <tr>
    <td class="header__cell">
      <center>

        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>

              <table class="row">
                <tr>
                  <td class="shop-name__cell">
                    {%- if shop.email_logo_url %}
                      <img src="{{shop.email_logo_url}}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" width="{{ shop.email_logo_width }}">
                    {%- else %}
                      <h1 class="shop-name__text">
                        <a href="https://winknod.com" style="color:#0081c3;text-decoration:none">Wink & Nod</a>
                      </h1>
                    {%- endif %}
                  </td>

                    <td class="order-number__cell">
                      <span class="order-number__text">
                        Order {{ order_name }}
                      </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

          <table class="row content">
  <tr>
    <td class="content__cell">
      <center>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>

            <h2>{{ email_title }}</h2>
            <p>{{ email_body }}</p>
            {% if order_status_url %}
              <table class="row actions">
  <tr>
    <td class="actions__cell">
      <table class="button main-action-cell">
        <tr>
          <td class="button__cell"><a href="{{ order_status_url }}" class="button__text">View your order</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      {% if shop.url %}
    <table class="link secondary-action-cell">
      <tr>
        <td class="link__cell"><a href="{{ shop.url }}" class="link__text"><span class='or'>or</span> Visit our store</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
{% endif %}

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

            {% else %}
              {% if shop.url %}
    <table class="row actions">
      <tr>
        <td class="actions__cell">
          <table class="button main-action-cell">
            <tr>
              <td class="button__cell"><a href="{{ shop.url }}" class="button__text">Visit our store</a></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
{% endif %}

            {% endif %}

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

          <table class="row section">
  <tr>
    <td class="section__cell">
      <center>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>Order summary</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>


<table class="row">
  {% for line in line_items %}
  <tr class="order-list__item">
    <td class="order-list__item__cell">
      <table>
        <td>
          {% if line.image %}
            <img src="{{ line | img_url: 'compact_cropped' }}" align="left" width="60" height="60" class="order-list__product-image"/>
          {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td class="order-list__product-description-cell">
          {% if line.product.title %}
            {% assign line_title = line.product.title %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign line_title = line.title %}
          {% endif %}

          {% if line.quantity < line.quantity %}
            {% capture line_display %} {{ line.quantity }} of {{ line.quantity }} {% endcapture %}
          {% else %}
            {% assign line_display = line.quantity  %}
          {% endif %}

          <span class="order-list__item-title">{{ line_title }} × {{ line_display }}</span><br/>

          {% if line.variant.title != 'Default Title' %}
            <span class="order-list__item-variant">{{ line.variant.title }}</span>
          {% endif %}
        </td>
          <td class="order-list__price-cell">
            {% if line.original_line_price != line.line_price %}
              <del class="order-list__item-original-price">{{ line.original_line_price | money }}</del>
            {% endif %}
            <p class="order-list__item-price">{{ line.line_price | money }}</p>
          </td>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>{% endfor %}
</table>

            <table class="row subtotal-lines">
  <tr>
    <td class="subtotal-spacer"></td>
    <td>
      <table class="row subtotal-table">
        {% if discounts %}
          {% capture discount_title %}Discount {% if discounts.first.code %}({{ discounts.first.code }}){% endif %}{% endcapture %}

<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>{{ discount_title }}</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ discounts_savings | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

        {% endif %}


<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>Subtotal</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ subtotal_price | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>


<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>Shipping</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ shipping_price | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>


        {% for line in tax_lines %}

<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>{{ line.title }}</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ line.price | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

        {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <table class="row subtotal-table subtotal-table--total">

<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>Total</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ total_price | money_with_currency }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

      </table>

      {% assign transaction_size = 0 %}
      {% for transaction in transactions %}
        {% unless transaction.kind == "capture" or transaction.kind == "void" %}
          {% assign transaction_size = transaction_size | plus: 1 %}
        {% endunless %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if transaction_size > 1 %}
        <table class="row subtotal-table">
          <tr><td colspan="2" class="subtotal-table__line"></td></tr>
          <tr><td colspan="2" class="subtotal-table__small-space"></td></tr>

          {% for transaction in transactions %}
            {% if transaction.status == "success" and transaction.kind == "authorization" or transaction.kind == "sale" %}
              {% if transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company %}
                {% capture transaction_name %}{{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company }} (ending in {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_last_four_digits }}){% endcapture %}
              {% else %}
                {% capture transaction_name %}{{ transaction.gateway | replace: "_", " " | capitalize }}{% endcapture %}
              {% endif %}


<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>{{transaction_name}}</span>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>{{ transaction.amount | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

            {% endif %}
            {% if transaction.kind == 'refund' %}
              {% if transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company %}
                {% assign refund_method_title = transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company %}
              {% else %}
                {% assign refund_method_title = transaction.gateway %}
              {% endif %}


<tr class="subtotal-line">
  <td class="subtotal-line__title">
    <p>
      <span>Refund</span>
        <br>
        <small>{{ refund_method_title | capitalize }}</small>
    </p>
  </td>
  <td class="subtotal-line__value">
    <strong>- {{ transaction.amount | money }}</strong>
  </td>
</tr>

            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      {% endif %}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

          <table class="row section">
  <tr>
    <td class="section__cell">
      <center>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h3>Customer information</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>

            <table class="row">
              <tr>
                {% if requires_shipping and shipping_address %}
                <td class="customer-info__item">
                  <h4>Shipping address</h4>
                  {{ shipping_address | format_address }}
                </td>
                {% endif %}
                {% if billing_address %}
                <td class="customer-info__item">
                  <h4>Billing address</h4>
                  {{ billing_address | format_address }}
                </td>
                {% endif %}
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="row">
              <tr>
                {% if requires_shipping and shipping_address %}
                <td class="customer-info__item">
                  <h4>Shipping method</h4>
                  <p>{{ shipping_method.title }}</p>
                </td>
                {% endif %}
                {% assign transaction_count = transactions | size %}
                {% if transaction_count > 0 %}
                <td class="customer-info__item">
                  <h4>Payment method</h4>
                  {% for transaction in transactions %}
                    {% if transaction.status == "success" or transaction.status == "pending" %}
                      {% if transaction.kind == "authorization" or transaction.kind == "sale" %}
                        <p class="customer-info__item-content">
                          {% if transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company %}
                            {% capture credit_card_url %}notifications/{{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_company | downcase | replace: " ", "_" }}.png{% endcapture %}
                            <img src="{{ credit_card_url | shopify_asset_url }}" class="customer-info__item-credit" height="24">
                            <span>Ending in {{ transaction.payment_details.credit_card_last_four_digits }} — <strong>{{ total_price | money }}</strong></span>
                          {% else %}
                            {{ transaction.gateway | replace: "_", " " | capitalize }} — <strong>{{ transaction.amount | money }}</strong>
                          {% endif %}
                        </p>
                      {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </td>
                {% endif %}
              </tr>
            </table>

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

          <table class="row footer">
  <tr>
    <td class="footer__cell">
      <center>
        <table class="container">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <p class="disclaimer__subtext">If you have any questions, reply to this email or contact us at <a href="mailto:{{ shop.email }}">{{ shop.email }}</a></p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </center>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<img src="{{ 'notifications/spacer.png' | shopify_asset_url }}" class="spacer" height="1" />

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I place out of stock quantity test order from Shopify admin and check email, I always get a normal email with else statement email instead of if email sentence must be printed. What is wrong with my `if` block? or is there any dependency? I am always placing out of stock product for sure. If entire code is required, ready to share.Thanks.